# How to split regex space and punctuation matches, but keep the punctuation in the resulting array?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to split a string with regex matching spaces, commas, question marks, and exclamation points.  But I'd like to include the matched punctuation in the resulting array (Spaces should be discarded.)  For example:

> Regex irritates me, I can't take it!

the string above should split() to:

> ["Regex", "irritates", "me", ",", "I", "can't", "take", "it", "!"]

I'm starting easy with just spaces and commas for now; I have the following code:

```
inputStr.split(/\s|(,)/);
```

Unfortunately, it gives me undefined items - I'm doing it wrong.  I spent a couple hours researching (as usual) and coming up empty.  I read about "lookahead" but can't figure it out either.  Can any regex gurus give me a hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `String.prototype.match()` with `RegExp` `/(\w+'\w+)|\w+|,|\!/g`

- `(\w+'\w+)` Matches `\w+'\w+` and remembers the match. These are called capturing groups. `\w+'\w+` matches any alphanumeric character from the basic Latin alphabet, including the underscore. Equivalent to [A-Za-z0-9_] , followed by match apostrophe , followed by match alphanumeric character.
  `+` matches the preceding item `\w` 1 or more times. Equivalent to {1,}.
- `\w+` Matches any alphanumeric character from the basic Latin alphabet, including the underscore.
- `,` Matches comma
- `\!` Matches exclamation mark

See [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

```js
var str = "Regex irritates me, I can't take it!";
var res = str.match(/(\w+'\w+)|\w+|,|\!/g);
console.log(res)
```

Comment: That works! Thank you!  Now I need to reverse engineer it figure out why...  unless you care to explain ;)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!  Holy cow I think I'm too tired (er..hungover) to try to understand it right now...

Answer (score 0):

This should work

String pat="Regex irritates me, I can't take it!"

pat.split("\s");

Answer (score 0):

The regex string is ([\w'!,]*)\S

Explanation:

- the ( ) captures groups.
- the [ \w'! ]* captures any word character, apostrophe, or exclamation
- the \S will not capture the space.

Try it in regexpal.com